# Perl's Net::FTPSSL analogue for Java or how to use ftp over SSL in Java

Tags: java, perl, ssl, ftp

I need to migrate code from Perl to Java.

I have this code in perl:

```
use Net::FTPSSL;

print "RUN\n";
my $ftpdebug    = 0;
my $ip          = "...";
my $port        = 2121;
my $atmpassword = "...";
my $atmuser     = "...";

my $ftp = Net::FTPSSL->new( $ip, Port => $port, Debug => $ftpdebug );

if ($ftp) {
    print "SUCCESS\n";
    $ftp->login( $atmuser, $atmpassword );
    print "LOGIN \n";
    @list = $ftp->list();
    for $i (@list) {
        print $i . "\n";
    }
} else {
    print "FAIL\n";
}
```

and it works fine. It's output me a list of files on a server.
But when I try to do this in Java using same host and port I can't even connect to a server.
I am trying:

```
try {
    FTPSClient ftpClient = new FTPSClient(false);

    // Connect to host
    ftpClient.connect(host, 2121);
    int reply = ftpClient.getReplyCode();
    if (FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(reply)) {

        // Login
        if (ftpClient.login(name, password)) {

            // Set protection buffer size
            ftpClient.execPBSZ(0);
            // Set data channel protection to private
            ftpClient.execPROT("P");
            // Enter local passive mode
            ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
            log.info(ftpClient.printWorkingDirectory());
            // Logout
            ftpClient.logout();

        } else {
            log.info("FTP login failed");
        }

        // Disconnect
        ftpClient.disconnect();

    } else {
        log.info("FTP connect to host failed: " + reply);
    }
} catch (IOException ioe) {
    log.info("FTP client received network error");
    log.info(ioe.getMessage());
    ioe.printStackTrace();
} catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException nsae) {
    log.info("FTP client could not use SSL algorithm");
}
```

And it fails on this line:

```
ftpClient.connect(host, 2121);
```

The erros is:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateExpiredException: NotAfter: Fri Dec 19 15:47:22 EET 2008
```

As I understand FTPSClient using the same protocol as Net::FTPSSL - FTP over SSL. So what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> As I understand FTPSClient using the same protocol as Net::FTPSSL - FTP over SSL.

Net::FTPSSL does not verify the certificate by default (and is thus open for man-in-the-middle attacks). FTPSClient instead verifies the certificate and croaks, because the certificate was already expired in 2008: "CertificateExpiredException: NotAfter: Fri Dec 19 15:47:22 EET 2008".

> As I understand FTPSClient using the same protocol as Net::FTPSSL - FTP over SSL.

You try to connect to a site with an invalid (because expired) certificate. FTPSClient correctly refuses to connect whereas Net::FTPSSL blindly connects.

Comment: Thank you. Could you please tell me how to connect without certificate (I understand that it's unsafe) using FTPSClient?

Comment: I have no experience with FTPSClient, but from the documentation it looks like you have to add your own TrustManager, so maybe just search for a TrustManager which trusts all certs. But note, that by not validating the certificate you allow man-in-the-middle attacks and thus defeat the main purpose of using FTPS instead of unencrypted FTP. Maybe you should look instead for a TrustManager which verifies the certificate fingerprint, so that you can be at least sure that you connect to a specific certificate even it is expired.

Comment: I understand that it's not proper to use FTPS without validation, but I have to migrate an existing code, which uses Net::FTPSSL without validation. But I'll think about the validation.

Answer (score 0):

This code works fine. But as @Steffen Ullrich told it's unsafe way.

```
        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
        TrustManager tm = new X509TrustManager() {
            public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
            }

            public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
            }

            public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                return null;
            }
        };
        sslContext.init(null, new TrustManager[] { tm }, null);
        FTPSClient ftpClient = new FTPSClient(sslContext);
```